# Laravel 5.4 Getting Call to a member function fill() on null

Tags: laravel

I am trying to save image on database to be used as background for the website. The problem is, I am getting `Call to a member function fill() on null`

Here is what I did

https://paste.laravel.io/ZoWBM

Answer (score 0):

This simply means there is no any record in `SiteSettings` model with `name_setting = $key`.

You should always do a check like this:

```
if (is_null($siteSettingsUpdate)) {
    // There is no such record in DB.
}
```